# How to make javascript regex work in postgresql regexp_matches?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm looking to capture all percents that's less than 30% with max 4 decimal places in a document.

Here's a working javascript regex sample: https://regex101.com/r/iM3nX5/5

When I use this regex `\b(?:[1-2]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4})\b[^a-zA-Z\d<]{0,3}%?` in Postgres, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('11111
11111.
11111.1111
.11111
a111.1111
99
010
101
100
100.01
2.95%
19.5113%
5.32
0.0250
9.32
24.32
0.0023
30.20
29.23', '\b(?:[1-2]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4})\b[^a-zA-Z\d<]{0,3}%?', 'g')
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing to make it work in Postgres?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word boundaries are a culprit. You need to use `\m` / `\M` to match leading/trailing word boundaries, or `\y` that is equivalent of `\b`. See the [Table 9.20. Regular Expression Constraint Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

> `\m`   matches only at the beginning of a word
>   `\M`   matches only at the end of a word
>   `\y`   matches only at the beginning or end of a word

E.g. you may use

```
'\m(?:[1-2]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4})\M[^a-zA-Z\d<]{0,3}%?'
```

Or

```
'\y(?:[1-2]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4})\y[^a-zA-Z\d<]{0,3}%?'
```

See the [PostgreSQL demo online](https://rextester.com/CDPYD62691). Results:

[image]